# Inserção de varias linhas GET automaticamente php

Tags: php, mysql, json, get

Tenho varias linhas como essa:

```
http://192.168.0.1/feed/data.json?id=71667&start=1426031940000&end=1426064520000&interval=30
http://192.168.0.1/feed/data.json?id=71667&start=1426031940000&end=1426064520000&interval=30
http://192.168.0.1/feed/data.json?id=71667&start=1426031940000&end=1426064520000&interval=30
http://192.168.0.1/feed/data.json?id=71667&start=1426031940000&end=1426064520000&interval=30
http://192.168.0.1/feed/data.json?id=71667&start=1426031940000&end=1426064520000&interval=30
http://192.168.0.1/feed/data.json?id=71667&start=1426031940000&end=1426064520000&interval=30
http://192.168.0.1/feed/data.json?id=71667&start=1426031940000&end=1426064520000&interval=30
```

Preciso executalas para fazer uma inserção no banco,como poderia fazer automaticamente ?

Comment: onde estao essas url? executar como ? vc tem várias possibilidades por ex fazer uma requisição em curl ou um file_get_contents do php. mostre o q vc esta tentando fazer e qual linguagem ta usando e de que forma quer q isso ocorra.

Comment: As uls,tenho elas em um arquivo .txt , pois o trouxe de um log,e preciso executa-las no navegador,porque elas são um GET que vão alimentar um banco de dados,e como se eu fosse la no navegador e digitasse uma linha dessa ai,mais como são muitas,gostaria de automatizar,e lembrando,isso sera feito somente uma vez para reparar um banco de dados que se perdeu.

Comment: Posso colocar eles links em um banco de dados também,ou csv ou da forma que for melhor

Comment: outra pergunta vc precisa que isso seja processado no backend ou no front ou tanto faz? pois tem vários jeitos de fazer isso.

Comment: tanto faz,pois só farei isso 1 vez,depois nunca mais.

Comment: Basta salvar como .csv e importar pelo MySQL Workbench (ou outro cliente de MySQL equivalente), ou mesmo colar num editor de código, inserir aspas no começo, aspas e virgula no fim (quase qualquer editor faz isso com facilidade em todas as linhas) e colocar o comando INSERT no começo. Pra por aspas e virgula basta um replace.

Comment: Exemplo: http://pastebin.com/REmx6qLb - devo ter gasto uns 30 segundos no máximo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguinte vc vou postar um POG aqui:

Método: POG ( c nao sabe o q he pog procura no google kkk )

vai colocar suas url num db e dai buscar com um selct normal so que ai vc printa um iframe com o link que carregar, assim:

```
$sql="Select * from minhatabela";
$query=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   echo "<iframe src='$result[url]'></iframe>";
}
```

caso queira outros métodos me avisa que complemento.

Comment: Entendi,vai rolar mesmo,vou testar aqui

Comment: ^^ c der certo avisa , abraço

Comment: Ok,quando tiver tempo se puder passar outras formas que conhecer,somente para base de conhecimento mesmo,seria bem útil.

Comment: vc pode fazer um while carregando o conteudo da url usando o get_file_contents ou fazendo uma requisição em curl, se tiver no linux pode fazer um array com as vars e executar o wget se fosse em kornshell

Comment: op da um votin pela boa vontade ai e conclui c deu certo